# Incorrect version of Airflow inside the docker containers

Tags: docker-compose, airflow

I'm trying to run Airflow using official docker-compose file, but my docker containers (airflow-webserver, airflow-scheduler, airflow-worker, airflow-triggerer) are constantly restarting.

When I look at logs in container it shows warnings as below:

```
airflow_drck-airflow-webserver-1  | /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:408 FutureWarning: The auth_backends setting in [api] has had airflow.api.auth.backend.session added in the running config, which is needed by the UI. Please update your config before Apache Airflow 3.0.
airflow_drck-airflow-webserver-1  | /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_config.py:1001 DeprecationWarning: The namespace option in [kubernetes] has been moved to the namespace option in [kubernetes_executor] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
airflow_drck-airflow-webserver-1  | ERROR: You need to upgrade the database. Please run `airflow db upgrade`. Make sure the command is run using Airflow version 2.6.1.
```

It seems like there is a problem with airflow version. Airflow version specified in the docker-compose file  is **2.3.3**.

But when I check `airflow version` inside docker container it shows **2.6.1**:

```
default@5c1f84edc227:/opt/airflow$ airflow version
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:408 FutureWarning: The auth_backends setting in [api] has had airflow.api.auth.backend.session added in the running config, which is needed by the UI. Please update your config before Apache Airflow 3.0.
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_config.py:1001 DeprecationWarning: The namespace option in [kubernetes] has been moved to the namespace option in [kubernetes_executor] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
2.6.1
```

Why is the Airflow version being updated?

Comment: there is not enough information. please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @AndreyBienkowski, I tried to add the code from the docker-compose file to the question, but for some reason the site did not allow me to do this and showed an error "your question appears to be spam".  And I had to remove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it will be useful to someone, the problem was related to dependencies _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS in docker-compose file.
After specifying the version for the apache-airflow-providers-oracle==3.4.0, the problem was solved.